# Which one of these two MATLAB string concatenation methods is faster?

Tags: string, matlab

Which one of the following ways to concatenate two strings is the fastest?

```
test = ['ssd' 'sdsd'];
```

```
test = sprintf('%s%s', string1, string2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple test reveals that

```
test = ['ssd''sdsd'];
```

is faster.

Specifically:

```
tic; for t=1:10000; test = ['ssd' 'sdsd']; end; toc;                
Elapsed time is 0.105972 seconds.
```

while

```
tic; for t=1:10000; test = sprintf('%s%s', 'ssd', 'sdsd'); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.211863 seconds.
```